# Correct spacing used between numbers and abbreviations

Tags: writing, abbreviations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Punctuation with units](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2794/punctuation-with-units)
>   [How to write units?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15953/how-to-write-units)

I see many people don't use a space between a numeral and an abbreviation, such as "7lb" or "5mm".  Shouldn't it be "7 lbs." and "5 mm"?  Otherwise, a baby may be confused to weigh "71 lbs." rather than "7 lbs."  Also, is there a period used after millimeter? (Ex. mm.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write units?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15953/how-to-write-units) or [When is it appropriate to use non-breaking spaces?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28467), or [Punctuation with units](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2794),

Comment: Also [Is it correct to say "a 5-mm-thick layer"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8666),

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the thing about pounds. if you read it `71 bs` it doesn't make sense. However, there should always be a space between the number and the unit to prevent confusion (although I can't see how there would be confusion in then case you stated).

As to the period. The rule of the thumb is that metric measurements should never receive a period and US customary measurements should always receive a period (so, `*5 mm.` would be incorrect).

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

In our journals we always use a space between the number and the unit of measurement. And we do not use periods after units of measurement, whether metric or not. It is a matter of style, not grammar.